# Double integrals: How to choose the order of the limits of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to calculate the integral of $|x|$ in the region that you see here: [image]

I have some doubts about the point from which start to integrate and about the order that I have to follow for the limits of integration.

For example, I have thought to start from top to bottom:

$$\int_{1}^{0} \int_{0}^{1}x \,dx\,dy+\int_{0}^{-1} \int_{1}^{0}x \,dx\,dy+\int_{-1}^{-5/2} \int_{0}^{-3/2}-x \,dx\,dy+\int_{-5/2}^{-4} \int_{-3/2}^{0}-x \,dx\,dy$$

but, if I follow this order, I obtain 0.... :/ (I haven't the result of this integral, so I can't decide if I have done in the correct way...) Can you help me?

Comment: Your double integrals are set up to be over rectangular regions. Do you know how to describe a region bounded by two curves in either the vertical or horizontal direction?

Comment: I'm curious, what is your native language? It should be "limits of integration".

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid you're right.. I have forgotten to say that I'll multiply each integrals for 1/2... But I don't think that it is the best way...

Comment: @avid.. don't ask me it!! I live in a terrible country! ahahah!! I have just corrected the mistake.. thanks! ;)

Comment: One can solve this step-by-step and as geometrically as possible: For every domain $D$ call $I(D)$ the integral of $|x|$ on $D$, then if $T$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, one computes $$I(T)=\frac16.$$ The domain of integration is made of four triangles, integrating $|x|$ on these is equivalent to integrating $|x|$ twice on $T$ and twice on $\frac32T$. Now, $I(\lambda D)=\lambda^3I(D)$ for every nonnegative $\lambda$ (why?) hence the desired integral is $$2\cdot I(T)+2\cdot \left(\frac32\right)^3\cdot I(T)=2\cdot\frac16\cdot\left(1+\frac{27}8\right)=\frac{35}{24}.$$

Comment: Note finally that the simplest approach to the computation of $I(T)$ might be to compute $I(C)$ for $C$ the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, since, by symmetry, $I(T)=\frac12\cdot I(C)$.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to integrate $-x$ over the interval $I_1=[-\frac{3}{2},0]$ and $+x$ over the interval $I_2=(0,1]$. Over $I_1$ the integration with respect to $y$ at a given $x$ would go from $-x-4$ to $x-1$; Over $I_2$ the integration with respect to $y$ would go from $x-1$ to $-x+1$:

So

$$I=\iint_A|x|dydx=\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^0(-x)\int_{-x-4}^{x-1}\ dy\ dx+\int_0^1x\int_{x-1}^{-x+1}\ dy\ dx.$$

---

1. $$-x\int_{-x-4}^{x-1}\ dy=-2x^2-3x.$$
2. $$x\int_{x-1}^{-x+1}\ dy=-2x^2+2x$$
3. $$\int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^0-2x^2-3x\ dx=\left[-\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2\right]_{-\frac{3}{2}}^0=\frac{9}{8}.$$
4. $$\int_0^1-2x^2+2x\ dx =\left[-\frac{2}{3}x^3+x^2\right]_{0}^{1}=-\frac{2}{3}+1=\frac{1}{3}$$

---

Finally:

$$I=\frac{9}{8}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{35}{24}.$$

Comment: oh, they are normal domains of integration..... A lot of thanks! I was desperate!! Thanks again for your kindness and for the patience that you had in writing the answer!